# string.len() always returns the error "unexpected symbol"

Tags: lua

```
function Main(Inhalt)

print(string.len(Inhalt))
end

Main(Bla)
```

This is just a example, I run in multiple problems like: `"input:3: bad argument #1 to 'len' (string expected, got nil)"` (Like here), or anything else with unexpected.

I'm kinda new to this, so please explain it to me from ground up I'm trying to figure out for a pretty long time. I already tried to convert this to a string with `tostring()`, but yes I'm missing something. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Lua has a great getting started book, i suggest you give it a read: https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case `Bla` either needs to be a string which you can fix by putting quotes around it

```lua
function Main(Inhalt)
   print(string.len(Inhalt))
end

Main("Bla")
```

or needs to be a variable that contains a string

```lua
Bla="test string"

function Main(Inhalt)
   print(string.len(Inhalt))
end

Main(Bla)
```

Comment: Ahh, so I have to define it all the time when i create a function? How do i have to handle it when it's not a string? Like a boolean or sth. else?

Comment: @ReySKR: Anything that's not a string would be an invalid argument to `string.len`. You could always call `tostring` on the argument to avoid an error, but I don't know that it's useful to get the string length of a non-string.

Answer (score 1):

Not a `lua` expert but it seems like you're trying to get the `length` of the string value `Bla`. The way you've written it right now does not indicate `Bla` is of string type. If you change it to the following, this should work.

```
function Main(Inhalt)
 print(string.len(Inhalt))
end

Main("Bla")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string1 = "Bla"
Main(string1)
```

In your code snippet `Bla` is not defined. Strings are surrounded by "".